# Input Field Only Accepting Numeric Value Using Directive In Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am new to Vue.js. I want an input field which accepts only numeric numbers and if the user enters any other value it will be replace with the empty string. Therefore, I want to add a custom directive to this field viz 'numericOnly'.

Code for custom directive :

```
Vue.directive('numericOnly', {
  bind (el, binding, vnode) {
    regex = /^[0-9]*$/
    if(!regex.test(el.value)){
     el.value = el.value.slice(0, -1)
    }
  }
})
```

Here is my template :

```
<input v-numericOnly name="mobileNumber" placeholder="Mobile Number" >
```

But it runs only the one time when the input field is bound to the DOM.

Please help me figure out this problem. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your directive should listen `keyup` of the input element to achieve what you need:

```
Vue.directive('numericOnly', {
  bind(el) {
    el.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
      let regex = /^[0-9]*$/
      if (!regex.test(el.value)) {
        el.value = el.value.slice(0, -1)
      }
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: Say some thing about your code how it answer the op Question?

Comment: @ShreeKhanal, I added a bit :)

Comment: Thank you @BobDust. We have to removeListner on unbind in this case.

Comment: v-model on this element is not getting updated in this case.

Answer (score 6):

```
import Vue from 'vue'    
Vue.directive('numericOnly', {
bind(el, binding, vnode) {
    el.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
        if ([46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190].indexOf(e.keyCode) !== -1 ||
            // Allow: Ctrl+A
            (e.keyCode === 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
            // Allow: Ctrl+C
            (e.keyCode === 67 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
            // Allow: Ctrl+X
            (e.keyCode === 88 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
            // Allow: home, end, left, right
            (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
            // let it happen, don't do anything
            return
        }
        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
        if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
            e.preventDefault()
        }
    })
}
```

})

Comment: prevent user from writing character in textbox only allow numbers
for example if you have a textbox for age and want user to write only number

Comment: a working example for demonstrate the code above
https://jsfiddle.net/AnasRezk/roLtf9wq/

Comment: you can type in 1.......... or .........., so not really a solution. or 1.1.1.1.1..1